# jQuery selector val is 'undefined' when assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Working on MVC5 app.

I have some hidden inputs on my page.... But, for testing, I changed the type to "text"...

```
<input type="text" id="selectedDate" value="">
<input type="text" id="selectedStartDate" value="">
<input type="text" id="selectedEndDate" value="">
```

All 3 inputs have values. I can see them. But, in my javaScript I'm encountering weird behavior. For example....

```
alert($("#selectedStartDate").val());
```

The above statement displays an alert with the proper value. BUT, if I try to assign this to a variable, it's undefined....

```
var startDate = $("selectedStartDate").val();
```

startDate is undefined. Any idea why? These 2 lines are literally adjacent in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing the  `#`in your selector, or is that a typo from copy/paste?

Comment: Um, yeah @Lixus. That's it. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the # in

```
var startDate = $("selectedStartDate").val();
```

Should be

```
var startDate = $("#selectedStartDate").val();
```